# How can I insert a value with a subscript into a dynamic ggplot title in a function?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to make a series of the same figures with different titles based on a variable name. The beginning of the title uses a variable name that *sometimes* has a subscript in it. I would like to either be able to specify the variable name in the function call or I could build it into the dataframe and call it from there. Here is an example of how I might try to specify it into the function call:

```
  library("tidyverse")
  
  plot <- function(title_abbr) {
    
    n_title <- 4
     
    mtcars %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = mpg)) +
      geom_point() +
      labs(title = bquote(paste({{ title_abbr }}, " ", "(", italic(reps) == .(n_title), ")")))
    
  }

  
 p1 <- plot(title_abbr = "Car"[2])
```

Other variable names may just be things such as "Driver" with no subscript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A safer way to accomplish this is to grab the unevaulated expression then inject that into the `bquote` without using `{{}}`. We can also avoid all that `paste` stuff by just using a complete expression using all the features `?plotmath` provides. For example

```
plot <- function(title_abbr) {
  expr_title <- rlang::enexpr(title_abbr)  
  n_title <- 4
  
  mtcars %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = mpg)) +
    geom_point() +
    labs(title = bquote(.(expr_title)~~(italic(reps) == .(n_title))))
}


plot(title_abbr = "Car"[2])
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know why, but this feels like a surprising use of syntax due to the lazy evaluation. I suppose you don't actually need the quotes here?

Comment: @AllanCameron True. In this case quotes don't really do anything, but if you did `plot(title_abbr = "Car Name"[2])` you'd need them. And I agree this is odd use for lazy evaluation that I would personally try to avoid in my own code.